# XML returning as a string, not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I don't fully understand why this won't work. I thought XML was easy to interact with, but I can't help but feel that the markup of the XML is causing the problem. I know its validate XML, but still:

**XML 79.xml**

```
<TREE xmlns:autn="http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/">
      <ITEM id="753" name="Report an IT Issue for a Corporate Finance Application." link="http://ithelp-remedy.gsk.com/ars/ITHelpHDsubmit_Application/SubmitProblemTicket.asp?qSummary=CORPFINANCEIT">
                 <HELPLINKS/>
      </ITEM>
</TREE>
```

Also worth noting this is the entire XML that i get back, shouldn't i have more detail in the xml header?

**jQuery**

```
 $.ajax({
     url:'xml/79.xml',
     dataType : 'xml',
     success: function(data){
         console.info(data);
     }
});
```

This will not return an object for me to play with :( How can I can I get it so that I can easily play with `data`

Comment: It should according to the jQuery docs, what is your console.log() showing ?

Comment: Better use Javascript for reading xml

Comment: `Object { readyState=1, setRequestHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}` Inside of this, i can see inside `responseText` the desired XML, but it is only return as a String, not an object

Comment: @PrasathK interesting.... i thought jQuery was JS ;) Care to give a little more info?

Comment: I don't know why you're getting a string but try using `$.parseXML(data)` in your success handler

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Visit this link http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp

Comment: @NikitaTkachenko 1.8.3 I'll read up on these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
     url:'xml/79.xml',
     dataType : 'text',
     success: function(data){
        //I'm adding the xml tags alright, but I don't think you
        //really need to, or you could just put a check.
        var omgXmlObj = $($.parseXML('<xml>' + data + '</xml>'));
        console.log(omgXmlObj.find('TREE'));
        console.log(omgXmlObj.find('TREE').attr('xmlns:autn'));
     }
});
```

Comment: I'll edit it a bit, but fantastic. Hadn't thought to just give the dataType as text, but the real key here is wrapping the String returned in the `xml` tag and then parse it. :D

Comment: @JamieHutber Not only that, but also the $ wrapping around the parsed document object - i.e. $($.parseXML(....)). This opens the whole can of jQuery awesomeness (find, attr etc.). Also, as I've mentioned in the comments within the code snippet, there's no strict need to add the xml tags. In this case, even if you omit the xml tags, you can still build your doc and play around with it. I just do it for a sub-conscious feel good factor that I can't really justify, ha ha.

Comment: ha, ye obivously, i always wrap all my tags with needless elements :p
But yes, like you say, I have wrapped all the things coming out of the elements with the $ so i can use jQuery on them. Good stuff dude :)

Answer (score 1):

According to jQuery documentation

> if you want a text response to be treated as XML, use "text xml" for
>   the dataType

so try doing it like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url:'xml/79.xml',
     dataType : 'text xml',
     success: function(data){
         console.info(data);
     }
});
```

Judging by the source code (_ajaxConvert function) it seems like there's no conversion at all if only one data type is specified, I may be wrong though

Comment: Still returns the object, but its in the correct direction. @refactor has the right of it.